# Error loading JSON from string in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a problem loading the following using json.loads()

```
json.loads("""{"columnName": "ML_Status_Flags_1.LAST_RESOLVED_DATE",
      "columnId": "3",
      "columnIndex": 5, 
      "formulaString": "\u003dGROUPBY(ASdate(Formatdate(#Remedy_CL_!LAST_RESOLVED_DATE_ML_Status_Flags_1;\"dd-MM-yyyy\");\"dd-MM-yyyy\"))"
    }""")
```

I got the following errors

```
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 9))
```

and At the end of the error I get this

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 4 column 106 (char 215)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your double quotes with a double backward slash `\\`:

```
json.loads("""{"columnName": "ML_Status_Flags_1.LAST_RESOLVED_DATE",
       "columnId": "3",
       "columnIndex": 5,
       "formulaString": "\u003dGROUPBY(ASdate(Formatdate(#Remedy_CL_!LAST_RESOLVED_DATE_ML_Status_Flags_1;\\"dd- MM-yyyy\\");\\"dd-MM-yyyy\\"))"
     }""")
```

Answer (score 2):

swap your double quotes for singles on the dates, I dont believe they are escaped with \ in a string

```
json.loads("""{"columnName": "ML_Status_Flags_1.LAST_RESOLVED_DATE",
      "columnId": "3",
      "columnIndex": 5, 
      "formulaString": "\u003dGROUPBY(ASdate(Formatdate(#Remedy_CL_!LAST_RESOLVED_DATE_ML_Status_Flags_1;'dd-MM-yyyy');'dd-MM-yyyy'))"
    }""")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a valid json. Adding 'r' before does the trick. See here for more info about 'r' and 'u': https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/7386332

The reason is that `\` is an escape character in Python and `r'` makes sure does are not taken into consideration.

```
import json

json.loads(r"""{"columnName": "ML_Status_Flags_1.LAST_RESOLVED_DATE",
      "columnId": "3",
      "columnIndex": 5, 
      "formulaString": "\u003dGROUPBY(ASdate(Formatdate(#Remedy_CL_!LAST_RESOLVED_DATE_ML_Status_Flags_1;\"dd-MM-yyyy\");\"dd-MM-yyyy\"))"
    }""")
```

Returns

```
{'columnId': '3',
 'columnIndex': 5,
 'columnName': 'ML_Status_Flags_1.LAST_RESOLVED_DATE',
 'formulaString': '=GROUPBY(ASdate(Formatdate(#Remedy_CL_!LAST_RESOLVED_DATE_ML_Status_Flags_1;"dd-MM-yyyy");"dd-MM-yyyy"))'}
```